# nodeValue from DOMDocument returning weird characters in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, domdocument, nodevalue

So I'm trying to parse HTML pages and looking for paragraphs (`<p>`) using `get_elements_by_tag_name('p');`

The problem is that when I use `$element->nodeValue`, it's returning weird characters. The document is loaded first into `$html` using curl then loading it into a DOMDocument.

I'm sure it has to do with charsets.

Here's an example of a response: "aujourdÃ¢Â€Â™hui".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the encoding of the html page in this particular example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issues and now noticed that loadHTML() no longer takes 2 parameters, so I had to find a different solution.  Using the following function in my DOM library, I was able to remove the funky characters from my HTML content.

```
private static function load_html($html)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);

    foreach ($doc->childNodes as $node)
        if ($node->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE)
            $doc->removeChild($node);

    $doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';

    return $doc;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently for me none of the above worked, finally I've found the following:

```
// Create a DOMDocument instance 
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// The fix: mb_convert_encoding conversion
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

[Source and more info](https://davidwalsh.name/domdocument-utf8-problem)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by forcing conversion to UTF-8 even though the original text was UTF-8:

```php
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8", $text);
$dom = new SmartDOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($webpage, 'UTF-8');
.
.
echo $node->nodeValue;
```

PHP is wierd :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an encoding issue. try explicitly setting the encoding to UTF-8.

this should help: http://devzone.zend.com/article/8855

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work... The funny thing is that if I do $doc->saveHTML(), the returning html's encoding is totally correct.

Comment: Whats the `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" ... />` specified in the HTML?